# Adding WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus broke Toolbar / shift icons to bottom

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am building Android application in Xamarin Forms and try to change my StatusBar color. On Page 1 it's blue and on Page 2 it's transparent. Unfortunately after using WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus flag my Toolbar icons positions are shifted to bottom.

For setting color on Page 1 to blue I am using:

```
Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
Window.SetStatusBarColor
```

For clearing color and having transparent StatusBar I am using:

```
Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
```

Unfortunately, when I do following: navigate to Page 2, then come back to root and navigate to Page 1 I see following result:
[image]

My navigation back arrow is lower than it should be. I've tried to set:

```
DecorView.SetFitsSystemWindows(false);
```

But it's not helping. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go through several questions & answers and find out that I miss extra paddings on Toolbar. It's probably related to Xamarin. Anyway this code help me solve issue:

```
       Toolbar.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.